# Alternatives to the Big-O notation?

Tags: language-agnostic, data-structures, big-o

Good afternoon all,

We say that a [hashtable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) has O(1) lookup (provided that we have the key), whereas a [linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) has O(1) lookup for the next node (provided that we have a reference to the current node).

However, due to how the [Big-O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) works, it is not very useful in expressing (or differentiating) the cost of an algorithm *x*, vs the cost of an algorithm *x + m*.

For example, even though we label both the hashtable's lookup and the linked list's lookup as O(1), these two O(1)s boil down to a very different number of steps indeed,

The linked list's lookup is fixed at *x* number of steps. However, the hashtable's lookup is **variable**. The cost of the hashtable's lookup depends on the cost of the hashing function, so the number of steps required for the hashtable's lookup is: *x + m*,

1. where *x* is a fixed number
2. and *m* is an unknown **variable** value

In other words, even though we call both operations O(1), the cost of the hashtable's lookup is a *magnitude* higher than the cost of the linked list's lookup.

The Big-O notation is specifically about the size of the input data collection. This does have its advantages, but it has its disadvantages as well, as can be seen when we collapse and normalize all non-*n* variables into 1. We cannot see the m variable (the hashing function) inside it anymore.

Besides the Big-O notation, Is there *another* (established) notation we can use for expressing  the fixed-cost O(1) which means *x* operations and the variable-cost O(1) which means *x + m* (*m*, the hashing function) number of operations?

Comment: From what I'm gathering, what you're looking for wouldn't have much notational purpose since it's plain to state in any language: It takes <X> many <step name>s to perform <algorithm>. (Where <step name> is context-specific.) Really, if there was some special notation, it wouldn't add anything other than "not big-O" which is clear because big-O isn't being stated.

Comment: @Kaganar The word *physical* seems to be causing some confusion here. I've removed the word *physical* from the question in hopes of making it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

> literal O(1) which means exactly 1 operation

Except it doesn't. The big O-Notation concerns relative comparision of complexity in relation to an input. If the algorithm does take a constant amount of steps, completely independent of the size of your input, than the exact amount of steps doesn't matter.

Take a look at the (informal) definition of O(n):

[image: informal definition of big O]

It means: There is a certain `k` so that for each `n` the function `f` is smaller than the function `g`.

In the case above, the hashtable lookup and linked list lookup would be `f`, and `g` would be `g(n) = 1`. For each case, you are able to find a `k` that `f(n) <= g(n) * k`.

Now, this `k` doesn't need to fixed, it can vary depending on platform, implementation, specific hardware. The only interesting point is that it exists. That's why both hashtable lookup and linked list node lookup are O(1): Both have a constant complexity, regardless of input. And when evaluating algorithms, that's what interesting, not the physical steps.

**Specifically concerning the Hashtable lookup**

Yes, the hash function does take a variable amount of operations (depending on implementation). However, it doesn't take a variable amount of operation depending on the size of the input. Big O-Nation is specifically about **the size of the input data collection**. A hash function takes **a single element**. For the evaluation of an algorithm it doesn't matter wether a certain function takes 10, 20, 50 or 100 operations, if the number of operations doesn't increase with the input size, it is O(1). There is no way to distinguish this in big O-Notation, as this isn't what big O-Notation is about.

Comment: That's what I'm talking about, the O notation does not talk about physical steps, at all. That's why I was wondering if there is another different notation for expressing the so-called literal O(1) which means exactly 1 operation.

Comment: There is no such thing as a literal O(1). O(1) is, strictly mathematically spoken, an infinite set of functions that are constant. An operation taking one physical step is a different metric altogether and should be treated as such.

Comment: Ok, I think I wasn't being clear, please take a look at the comment below Kaganar's post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10321079/632951#comment-13287875

Comment: I added something specifically about the hashtable lookup. Big O-Notation is about the amount of operations depending on the input collection size. If a algorithm evaluates in a constant amount of operations, regardless of input collection size, it is O(1).

Comment: What happens when we have two input variables *n* and *m* instead of a single input variable *n*? (btw I've edited the question if it would be clearer..) Basically I'm looking for *another* notation because the Big-O notation is specifically about the size of the input data collection. This does have its advantages, but it has its disadvantages as well, as can be seen when we collapse and normalize all non-*n* variables into 1. We cannot see the *m* variable (the hashing function) inside it anymore.

Comment: Even if you include it for every element, it will still be the same, for example, lets say we execute the hash function for each element, it would be `O(n*m) = O(n)` as `n*m` will still be surpassed by a function `n*k` with `k>=m`. There is no way of introducing this hashing function, in the end you'll always be able to remove it due to the nature of big O-Notation.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10519/discussion-between-pacerier-and-femaref)

Answer (score 2):

"~" includes the constant factor - see [the family of bachmann functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Theta_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the "number of operations" is highly context dependent. In fact, that's why big-O notation was invented -- it seems to work rather well in modelling a broad number of computers.

Besides, what a programmer things the number of "ops" is doesn't mean how much time it actually does take (e.g. is it already in cache?) or how many steps hardware actually takes (what does your processor do -exactly-? Does it have micro-ops?) or even how many operations are dictated to the processor (what is your compiler doing for you?). And those are all concerns, even when you try to define a precise concept that's abstract enough to be useful.

So. For now, it's Big-O vs. "operations" -- whatever "operations" means to you and your colleagues at the time.

Comment: No the keyword is "*fixed*", not "*physical*". The physical number of steps for the linked list's lookup is *fixed*, whereas the physical number of steps for the hashtable's lookup is *variable*. *(In other words, the physical cost of the hashtable's lookup will be a magnitude higher than the physical cost of the linked list's lookup.)* Is there a notation to express this difference?